# How to Post Encrypted request to external URL in asp.net core2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url, post

I have an existing asp.net application and trying to migrate it to netcoreapp2.1 (MVC). The following code posts to external URL in asp.net application

```
   if (DisplayType.SelectedValue == "1")
        {
            Form.Action = txt_payment_gateway_url.Text;
        }
        else if (DisplayType.SelectedValue == "2")
        {
            RedirectionURL.Value = txt_payment_gateway_url.Text;
        }
```

in asp.net core appliction im using this code to post the encryptd request to external apllication

```
     var result = PostEncryptedData(data, VM.PaymentGatewayURL);
   
   private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostEncryptedData1(Dictionary<string, string> encryptedData, string url)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> keyValuePairs = encryptedData.ToList();
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValuePairs);

        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        return await client.PostAsync(url, content);

    }
```

but during debug, it give me the result is not computed as shown
[Result is not computed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNxzd.png)

Answer (score 0):

it has to be `var result = await PostEncryptedData(data, VM.PaymentGatewayURL);`. you missed the `await`

```
Public async Task<your required return type> YourMethodName()
{ 
 var result = await PostEncryptedData(data, VM.PaymentGatewayURL);
 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @thanzeel for your reply but by adding await, it gives me Error Severity 
Error CS4033 The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

Comment: whats the error @Msama?

Comment: CS4033 The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

Comment: @Msama ,please change the calling method to Public async Task<your required return type> YourMethodName(){ var result = await PostEncryptedData(data, VM.PaymentGatewayURL); }

Comment: @Msama, i have uodated the answer. please check

Comment: after updating the function to public the error is still . CS4033 The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

Comment: updated to public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostEncryptedData(Dictionary<string, string> encryptedData, string ExternalURL)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> keyValuePairs = encryptedData.ToList();
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValuePairs);

            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            return await client.PostAsync(ExternalURL, content);

        }

Comment: is the problem solved?

Comment: Not yet, I added an external url parameter and trying to deal with it through view page

Comment: if you can produce a minimal working project then may be we can help you

Comment: I have Dictionary with 4 parameters which are encrypted as shown below: VM.SenderIdURL = (string)data["SenderID"]; VM.RandomSecret = (string)data["RandomSecret"]; VM.RequestObject = (string)data["RequestObject"]; VM.HasedRequestObject = (string)data["HasedRequestObject"]; if (VM.DisplayType == "1") { VM.ActionFormURL = Constants.ActionFormURL; } and I want to send(Post ) these encrypted data to external URL ... How can I perform some thing like this